# PowerShell Verbose-Parameter

Tags: powershell, logfile, verbose

I have a few questions about the verbose-parameter.
Example script:

```
try {
    New-Item -Path "C:\Test.txt" -ItemType "File" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
}
catch {
    Write-Host $Error[0]
}
```

Output:

```
VERBOSE: Execute the "Create file" operation for the target "Target: C:\Test.txt".
Access to the path "C: \ Test.txt" was denied.
```

How do I save the verbose message in a variable?

Is it possible to edit the verbose message automatically generated by PowerShell before saving it in a log file (add date and time)?
Example script (not working):

```
try {
    New-Item -Path "C:\Test.txt" -ItemType "File" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose *> $LogFile
}
catch {
    Write-Host $Error[0]
}
```

Are there better suggestions to write a "success" log file than with the parameter verbose and without having to write it manually?

Thank you!

Comment: The last question is a bit unclear - can you perhaps post an example of what you're currently describing/doing?

Comment: I added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the verbose output to a variable if you merge the `Verbose` stream into standard output stream (`4>&1`):

```bsh
$output = New-Item "C:\Test.txt" -ItemType "File" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose 4>&1
```

Since `New-Item` also returns the newly created file, you'll want to split the output into verbose vs normal again:

```bsh
$verboseOutput,$normalOutput = $output.Where({$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord]}, 'Split')
```

And now you can prepend timestamps to the records in `$verboseOutput` before writing them to disk